# Combine two list of dict to one dict by adding value of one list of dict as key to another

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 list of dict as:

```
lst1= [{'st_name': 'ram', 'st_email_id': 'ram@abc.com'}, {'st_name': 'Raj', 'st_email_id': 'raj@abc.com'}, {'st_name': 'jatin', 'st_email_id': 'jatin@abc.com'},{'st_name': 'tom', 'st_email_id': 'tom@abc.com'}]

lst2 = [{'team_name': 'Team1'}, {'team_name': 'Team2'}]
```

want something like this:

```
{
"team1":
[
    {
        'st_name': 'ram', 
        'st_email_id': 'ram@abc.com',
     
    },
    {
        'st_name': 'Raj',
        'st_email_id': 'raj@abc.com'
    }
],
"team2":
[
    {
        'st_name': 'jatin',
        'st_email_id': 'jatin@abc.com'
    },
    {
        'st_name': 'tom',
        'st_email_id': 'tom@abc.com'
    }
]
}
```

Comment: how do you know who belongs to which team?

Comment: Also, how does `Team1` become `team1`?

Comment: `{team['team_name'].lower(): roster for team, roster in zip(lst2, (lst1[:2],lst2[2:]))}`

Comment: i am mapping the team info from a table while creating api

Comment: {team['team_name'].lower(): roster for team, roster in zip(lst2, (lst1[:2],lst2[2:]))} this way we get only team 1

Answer (score 0):

(without considering how do you know who belongs to which team)

you can't combine/merge togheter 2 list of dictionaries in python, but you can create a new dictionary with `lst2` content as the keys and `lst1` content as the values.

note: my result isn't the same as what you requested, because is up to you what values you actually need inside the dictonary.

with that being said, the code i pretty simple:

```
lst1 = #dict_list with the values
lst2 = #dict_list with the keys

dict_final = {}
for key in lst2:
        dict_final[key['team_name']] = lst1 #<- lst1 should be replaced by your needs

print(dict_final)
```

final result:

```
{
    'Team1':
    [
        {
            'st_name': 'ram',
            'st_email_id': 'ram@abc.com'
        }, 
        {
            'st_name': 'Raj',
            'st_email_id': 'raj@abc.com'
        }, 
        {
            'st_name': 'jatin', 
            'st_email_id': 'jatin@abc.com'
        }, 
        {
            'st_name': 'tom', 
            'st_email_id': 'tom@abc.com'
        }
    ],
    'Team2': 
    [
        {
            'st_name': 'ram', 
            'st_email_id': 'ram@abc.com'
        },
        {
            'st_name': 'Raj',
            'st_email_id': 'raj@abc.com'
        }, 
        {
            'st_name': 'jatin', 
            'st_email_id': 'jatin@abc.com'
        },
        {
            'st_name': 'tom', 
            'st_email_id': 'tom@abc.com'
        }
    ]
}
```